# Show list of protected pages /read only pages in coveo search list

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, coveo

Not able to see list of protected pages at the time of Coveo Seach.

I have given read access permission to a non-extranet role for few pages, and if I search something in Coveo box then none of result comes. It only displaying list of public pages.

How I can show list of protected pages in search list.

I have access-denied page, so if someone will click on protected page then he will move to access denied page.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer! Everything bellow is with Coveo Enterprise Search 7.

I am not sure I fully understand your question but Coveo has two different security models.

1. Index Permissions: This is defined through the [Roles](https://onlinehelp.coveo.com/en/ces/7.0/administrator/about_administration_roles.htm) and will grant or denied access to users when searching in the [Index Browser](https://onlinehelp.coveo.com/en/ces/7.0/administrator/administration_tool_-_index_browser_menu.htm).
2. Document Permissions: These are permissions attached to the documents. The connector will index the documents and their permissions when indexing content and will use a [Security Provider](https://onlinehelp.coveo.com/en/ces/7.0/administrator/what_are_security_providers.htm) to identify the users at query-time. The Security Provider is attached to your source when you create it. By default, the Security Provider will update the Coveo Security Cache every 24 hours, but it can be changed manually. You can also set additional permissions or use late binding (security expansion at query time).

So if your user is not seeing documents in the Index Browser, then maybe the document has not been indexed or the Roles are not properly set.

If they do not see the document in a Coveo search page (.Net UI or JavaScript), then maybe there was an error when updating the security cache.

Comparing the permissions on the item in the Index Browser (Details > Permission) with the user querying (using the CES Console) is the best way to troubleshoot permission issues.

Hope it helps,
Simon